# python ImportError: No module named primes

Tags: python, importerror

I'm really new to Python.  I'm trying to import a third party module called primes.py.  I have placed this module in C:\Python26\Lib (the location where I installed Python). I then have another file which is trying to import this module.  The file attempting to import primes is located at C:\Python26.

In my Python file I have the following two lines:

```
import primes
import sys
```

When I run this file, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named primes
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put primes.py in the `lib/site-packages/` directory.

Also: no need to put your own Python files under the installation directory: I'd advise you to put them somewhere else (where it makes sense).

Comment: placed the file in that location, still getting the same error !!

Comment: are you positive that the exact filename is primes.py (mind the case-sensivity, make sure windows does not hide extensions). It may be helpful if you issue the results of 1. start a python shell (start --> run --> cmd --> python) 2. type `import sys; print sys.path` Paste results here...

Comment: >>> import sys;
>>> print sys.path
['', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python26.zip', 'C:\\Python26\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python26\
\lib', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python26
', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages']

thats what im getting

Comment: its working, i dont know what the problem was ... but its working now :| !! thanks ofr the help everyone !!

Answer (score 2):

The module needs to be on your PYTHONPATH or in the same directory as the script, app, or module that is trying to import the module.

I'm not a Windows programmer but if you have placed the module in 'C:\Python26\Lib' and your path is set to 'C:\Python26' you need to add '\Python26\Lib' to your PYTHONPATH. I'm not certain on what the syntax would be but it should be something like 'C:\Python26;C:\Python26\Lib'. Assuming everything is the same on Windows, the subdirectories are not searched automatically.

I think a more appropriate place to put the module is to place it in 'site-packages', I don't know how this is accomplished on Windows. On *nix systems there is a script 'setup.py' that comes with the package/module, and uses 'setuptools' to build and install the package/module for you.

Comment: iv tried putting the primes.py file both in the same directory as the file that is trying to import that module and i have also placed a copy in my pythonpath (C:\Python26) still no luck !!

Answer (score 1):

you probably should located this under `site-packages` directory **or** a private folder instead.  Check your `sys.path` to understand your `import` paths.

Comment: what do you mean by 

'check your sys.path' ??

Comment: I mean it is a good way to understand where your `import` problem might originate.

Comment: how do i go about doing this ?? sorry of thats a dumb question, like is said im new to the python world !!